# The section/subsection starts enumeration with a 0.X.X

Tags: sectioning, enumerate

I am not able to understand how to disable the feature that makes the enumeration of the sections as shown within the following image:

[image: Enumeration of section and subsection]

As you can see the enumeration is preceded by a `0`.

The package used are:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\input{./acronyms.tex}


\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

Any Idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to have a `\chapter` before a `\section`...

Comment: can you give en example, please? Sorry for that newbie question: I always use template

Comment: oh yes, that solved the problem. Please answer the question so I can accept it

Comment: You probably have somewhere in your document a `\section{Tutorial Scope and Aim}`. But with the `report` class you need to start a `\chapter` before using `\section` with `\chapter{Introduction}` (for example). This is a fairly common problem. I marked a duplicate

Comment: should I delete the question?

Comment: You don't have to. Duplicate questions are not necessarily a bad thing. Sometimes people search for things with different wordings, so two questions phrased differently which point to the same solution is perhaps easier to find for future readers. But of course, the question is yours, so you are free to do what you think is best :-)